# How to remove a specific page from Navigation cache in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I have set NavigationCacheMode to Required in some pages of my WP 8.1 XAML app. How can I remove a specific page from that? This is not Navigation stack.

Answer (score 5):

If a page has NavigationCacheMode set to **Required**, there is currently no way to remove it explicitly.

If you use **Enabled**, you can reset the cache using the cache mode:

```
private void ResetPageCache()
{
    var cacheSize = ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize;
    ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize = 0;
    ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize = cacheSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to remove the cache however I managed to get around it by simply setting NavigationCacheMode to Disabled when I click the refresh button in my application.

So when the page reloads it is then set back to required, works a treat for me!

```
private void refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
            Refresh.IsEnabled = false;
            switch (flipView.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["FlipView"] = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["FlipView"] = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["FlipView"] = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["FlipView"] = 3;
                    break;
            }
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is too easy.
Just use below code on page leave:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
```

And use below code on page constructor:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enable;
```

Comment: I set the cache mode to Disabled but when I navigate to that page it has the same info. Any ideas to why this is happening?