# WinRT - Navigate to specific page in the Navigation Stack

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have these pages on a windows project

> page1.xaml
>
> page2.xaml
>
> page3.xaml
>
> page4.xaml

After i do some operations on page1 i call this;

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(page2), document);
```

On page 2 i do some stuff with the document, then i navigate to page3.xaml

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(page3), document);
```

Then i do some more stuff on page 3 and go to page4.xaml.

And in page4.xaml i have a button that when pressed i want to go back to page2,xaml not a new one, but the same one i came from.

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To navigate to the same instance of `page2`, you need to set the Page's [`NavigationCacheMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode(v=win.10).aspx)  Property to `Enabled` or `Required` :

```
NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"
```

now the difference between those two is whether or not they take [CacheSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.cachesize.aspx) into consideration or not,
from msdn :

> The difference in behavior is that Enabled might not be cached if the frame's cache size limit (CacheSize) is exceeded, whereas Required always generates an entry no matter the size limit.

Comment: i see , so if i enable it when i do Frame.Navigate(typeof(page2), document); it would to to a cached version that i used before instead of a new instance of page2, right?. What if i wanted to navigate to a new instance of page2?

Comment: sorry i was editing my comment when you wrote yours, not sure if you read the second part : What if i wanted to navigate to a new instance of page2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134285/how-to-remove-a-specific-page-from-navigation-cache-in-windows-phone-8-1-rt